# android market account information tool

Tags: android, google-play

hallo,

is their a way to get information of an android market account(my account) for other poeple ? So that other poeple have a look on how it is without permission to change something.. (e.g.that financier have a look on it).

find nothing until now

LG j

Comment: What information specfically? How many apps you've created? How many people installed your apps? How many comments your apps received?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the only publically available information about a developer's account is the list of apps they've published, which are accessible from the URI `http://market.android.com/search?q=pub:<Developer Name>` or `market://search?q=pub:<Developer Name>` (from http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html), but I don't know of a way to get that information programmatically.

Comment: I mean those information which are also  accessible in developer account only for one app (e.g. the app which the financier finance)